# Multiplication of gigantic matrices [MATLAB], runs out of memory

Tags: matlab, memory, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply two gigantic matrices:  [1585152   90]*[90   1585152]. MATLAB runs out of memory. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: That's several terabytes of data. Are you sure you need to calculate all of that at once?

Comment: The workaround is to rethink your problem, and find a solution that doesn’t require such a multiplication.

Comment: It's essentially a 90-element vector product that's been repeated many times. Just do not store all of the data for repetitions in RAM at once. Use a file or database or something along the line.